# Calling external JavaScript function in full stack app

Tags: javascript, heroku

I have used JavaScript for a while, but am brand new to Node.js and full stack development, taking on a small project as a hobbyist.  I have Heroku set up to host the app at https://midi-writer.herokuapp.com/ and am able to edit my files and update the app (using git commands) through my Mac terminal.

I am having trouble figuring out how to call a JavaScript function in an external file (in /src/js/midiWriter.js) from the index.html page.  Using `<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>` doesn't work (I think that the file is 'bundled' when I push it to Heroku), and I have also tried `<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/js/midiWriter.js"></script>`

Here is the full code for index.html with the function call at the end of the script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Heart Beats</title>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>

<form id="jsonFile" name="jsonFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <h2>EKG File</h2>
     <input type='file' id='fileinput'>
     <input type='button' id='btnLoad' value='Load' onclick='loadFile();'>
     <hr>
     Frequency: <div id="frequency"></div>
     Metadata:<div id="metaData"></div>
     <div id="midiDownload">A link will appear here after the file has been processed</div>
  </fieldset>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

  function loadFile() {
    var input, file, fr;

    if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
      alert("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
      return;
    }

    input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
    if (!input) {
      alert("Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
    }
    else if (!input.files) {
      alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
    }
    else if (!input.files[0]) {
      alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
    }
    else {
      file = input.files[0];
      fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = receivedText;
      fr.readAsText(file);
     
    }

    function receivedText(e) {
      let lines = e.target.result;
      var newArr = JSON.parse(lines);
      var metaDataString = '';
      document.getElementById("frequency").innerHTML = newArr.frequency + " Hz";
      for (i = 0; i < newArr.meta.dashboard_measurements.length; i++){
        metaDataString += newArr.meta.dashboard_measurements[i].description + ": " 
            + newArr.meta.dashboard_measurements[i].value 
            + " " + newArr.meta.dashboard_measurements[i].unit  + "<br>";
      }
      document.getElementById("metaData").innerHTML = metaDataString;
    }
    midiWriter();
  }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the midiWriter.js file:

```
function midiWriter(){

var MidiWriter = require('midi-writer-js');
var track = new MidiWriter.Track();

track.addEvent([
        new MidiWriter.NoteEvent({pitch: ['E4','D4'], duration: '4'}),
        new MidiWriter.NoteEvent({pitch: ['C4'], duration: '2'}),
        new MidiWriter.NoteEvent({pitch: ['E4','D4'], duration: '4'}),
        new MidiWriter.NoteEvent({pitch: ['C4'], duration: '2'}),
        new MidiWriter.NoteEvent({pitch: ['C4', 'C4', 'C4', 'C4', 'D4', 'D4', 'D4', 'D4'], duration: '8'}),
        new MidiWriter.NoteEvent({pitch: ['E4','D4'], duration: '4'}),
        new MidiWriter.NoteEvent({pitch: ['C4'], duration: '2'})
    ], function(event, index) {
    return {sequential: true};
  }
);

var write = new MidiWriter.Writer(track);
console.log(write.dataUri());  

var app = document.getElementById('midiDownload');
var downloadLink = `<a href="${write.dataUri()}">Download Link</a>`;
app.innerHTML = downloadLink;
}
```

I get the Uncaught Reference Error "midiWriter is not defined" with this version.

Please excuse any lame errors!  I am brand new to this :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be like this:
In your html file:

```js
<script src="../src/js/midiWriter.js"></script>
<script>
   ...
   midiWriter();
</script>
```

What the first line does is set the source of the file you will use and the in the plain `script` tags, you can use any function or variable that has global scope and is declared in the file whose path you declared in the `<script src="">` tag.

Comment: When I try this, it is unable to locate the ../src/js/midiWriter.js.  I think it is because the individual .js files are bundled and so not accessible by calling the directory where they exist in the project?

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct? maybe its the path that is not correct. Copy and paste the correct path from ur file explorer (or whatever it is on mac)

Comment: Also, if you use express as backend then we tag these as static files so we provide a static path to it like provide the name of the folder that contains all the static files.

Comment: The function is in the backend...I think it is compiled and bundled with a bunch of its dependencies?  But  using the "bundle.js" path does not make the function available.  Interestingly, if midiWriter.js is not a function (the function term and brackets are removed from that file), then using src="bundle.js" executes it immediately

Answer (score 0):

Just hired someone on Fiverr to take a look.  The problem is that I need to define the external function globally using window.midiWriter = function (){...